# how I create the pointcloud topic in moveit in order to do the octomap?

Tags: kinect, moveit, octomap, ros-indigo, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody.

i have been wondering how to really create the pointcloud topic in moveit.

I did [This tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/src/doc/perception_configuration.html), but it only explains how to do once you have the topic done.

I tried to create a pointcloud topic using [iai_kinect2](https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2) (due to the fact that im using a kinect v2. and even if i am able to create a point cloud, if i put the topic in the yaml file, and i run a simulation, any octomap is shown.

I was wondering if i have also a set any specific parameter or something in planningscene.

I have been working on that a few days in I'm feeling I am doing many rounds on the same topic.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269599/how-i-create-the-pointcloud-topic-in-moveit-in-order-to-do-the-octomap?/) by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on ROS Answers with karma: 187 on 2017-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I respond myself also.

It seems that was missing the pose of the kinect in the environment.

In order to solve this problem, i just added to the launch file a tf2 with the name required (it is shown in rviz, when you try to open a pointcloud2 trough the desired topis, then it says that the frame with the name ____ is missing).

Good luck to everybody!

---

Originally posted by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) with karma: 187 on 2017-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1